# PowerPoint 2007 - Automatic layout for inserted objects check box

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

1. Why don't I have an Apply as you
   work check box for "Automatic layout
   for inserted objects" in the
   AutoCorrect dialog box of of
   PowerPoint 2007?
2. What I would really like is to turn
   it off\on programmatically. This
   code doesn't seem to do it: 
   `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AutoCorrect.DisplayAutoLayoutOptions
   = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AutoCorrect.DisplayAutoLayoutOptions = false`** just turns off the button for layout options that shows up, it won't disable auto layout.

Comment: The Addin I am developing adds grouped objects to the slide. If the slide contains placeholders then the objects are inserted to the placeholders automatically. and then I cannot group them!
I would like to stop this behavior and I can't rely on user actions. 
The way I by pass it nowadays  is by automatically change the layout to blank, insert the objects and then restore the layout. Though everything is done programmatically this solution has side effects, since other non related objects may move....
I prefer a different solution to the auto layout of inserted objects as placeholders.

Comment: also u didn't answer:
A. Why don't I have an Apply as you work check box for "Automatic layout for inserted objects" in the AutoCorrect dialog box of of ppt 2007?

In all three installations I have of the standard edition I don't have this option.

Comment: @dudia: You can totally get around this issue. I'm not sure what your code is for insertion, but you can completely avoid having something put in a placeholder. If you edit your post above and share your insertion code, I'd be happy to look at it and suggest an alternative way. On "Automatic Layout for Inserted Objects" - this wouldn't make sense to have because not every inserted object is automatically laid out.